# Em perguntas sobre bibliotecas, devemos incluir tag para a linguagem principal?

Tags: debate, tags, proposta-para-faq, big-7, syntax-highlighting

Estou pensando em casos de bibliotecas específicas de uma linguagem, como jQuery. Se a pergunta não possuir a tag JavaScript, precisamos incluir language hints para todos os blocos de código da pergunta e de suas respostas, ou o destaque de sintaxe (syntax highlighting) não funcionará automaticamente. Se toda pergunta sobre jQuery incluir a tag [javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) além de [jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jquery), esse problema não ocorre. Porém a inclusão dessa tag extra pode incentivar respostas que não utilizem a biblioteca em questão. No caso de js/jquery isso pode ser até uma vantagem, porém não tenho certeza se em outras situações isso pode atrapalhar.

Como acham que devemos proceder nesses casos?

Comment: Acho que vamos precisar de uma série que perguntas sobre isso. Vejo muita tag errada, mas não quero mexer sem todo mundo concordar. E esse tipo de pergunta faz parte das que devem ser feitas entre as big-7 que todo site deve ter.

Comment: Similar ao problema javascript/jquery. Em [tag:ruby] vejo o seguinte escrito: "A tag Ruby é para questões relacionadas com: [...] Qualquer coisa relacionada com o Ruby, **exceto** Ruby on Rails.". Eu discordo. Perguntas sobre uma biblioteca muitas vezes podem ser respondidas usando apenas a linguagem *core*. O que acham que seria correto por na tag? Qual deve ser o padrão para todos os casos desse tipo?

Answer (score 3):

Porque não utilizar o máximo de tags possível dentro do razoável?

Uma pergunta de de matplotlib com ipython-notebook não poderia levar a tag 'python'? Não vejo porque, já que ajudaria a contabilizar questões dentro do escopo da linguagem.

Imagino que uma desvantagem seja o fato de que a lista de perguntas com determinada tag generalista possa se tornar muito grande, mas nada que adicionar outra tag no campo de pesquisa não resolva.

Comment: Se não me engano o limite é 5. No caso do meu exemplo, "dentro do razoável" significa javascript + jquery, certo? Se você estiver dizendo para usar sempre 5, acho exagero.

Comment: Não sabia que o máximo eram cinco. Não acho que se deva utilizar tags simplesmente para se atingir o máximo.
Acho que devemos dar o máximo de informação possível para que o sistema possa categorizar e apresentar (além de contabilizar) as perguntas. Quanto ao seu exemplo, não falo javascriptnês. =(

Comment: Certo, concordo. Esquece meu exemplo, é que sua primeira frase pode dar a entender que quanto mais tags, melhor. Eu acho que linguagem + biblioteca + assunto bastam.

Answer (score 2):

Sim. É importante deixar claro qual a linguagem está se referindo. É útil para chamar a atenção da comunidade específica e para melhorar a indexação dos buscadores de conteúdo na internet.

Toda informação que adicione algo útil para classificar a pergunta deve ser usado, mesmo que gere um pouco de redundância.

Só não deve ser usado se for uma pergunta muita específica da biblioteca e nada relacionado com a linguagem, o que é extramente raro.